# Is it a good practice to also make relationship between left and very right table directly in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

Below is how my relational database in MySQL looks like:

```
[House]
id
street_id

[Street]
id
city_id
name

[City]
id
province_id
name

[Province]
id
name
```

With this structure when I have an ID of a house, I can get the province name in a relational chaining way following Laravel Eloquent as following.

```
$house = House::where(['id' => 1])->with('street.city.province')->firstOrFail();

$province = $house->street->city->province;
```

In some case, I do not need data in the `Street` and `City` table. I only need to know in which `Province` the house is. Is it a good practice to also connect the `House` table directly with the `Province` table as following?

```
[House]
id
street_id
province_id
```

By doing this, I can directly get province without chaining with `street` and `city` as following.

```
$house = House::where(['id' => 1])->with('province')->firstOrFail();

$province = $house->province;
```

Is it a good practice by doing so or over-killed because `House` is already connected by `Street` by `street_id`?

Comment: Well this question primarily opinion-based and matter of taste if you model it like that.. A house is in a county,  province and or street so it's not wierd if you add a `province_id` directly to the house table to mine opinion.. As  facts like `mine house is located in the country ....` or `mine house is located in the province ...` are valid.

Comment: I would like to following the most opinions, be to honest.

Comment: I wonder if adding both street_id and province_id is a good practice or over-killed.

Comment: hard to answer as i don't know which kind of SQL queries laraval generates with that code or how the tables like indexes are defined..

Comment: In case in a pure SQL query without a framework, what would you do?

Comment: Well also adding `province_id` to the house table is more or less reducent data which is most cases you want to avoid in most normalisation processing cases.. But when you have `province_id` in the house table you ask "give me all houses in the province..." (much) more cheap as you would require only one join instead of four but you would require more diskspace like 4 Mb per million records... *"what would you do?"* Well still hard to say both options sounds good it depends on the user case i geuss.

Comment: I rather avoid redundant data and feel like adding both street_id and province_id in the House table is over-killed and thing might go wrong when street_id and province_id are changed and you update only one of them in the House table, but in my real case, the chaining goes on with 7 tables. It is hard to decide what is a better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to also connect the `House` table directly with the `Province` table [by duplicating a column]

No. It's a bad practice that grew up in the early days of SQL when it was really slow at indexing/joining chains like that.

I don't see anything here that's a matter of opinion. You would be duplicating information in both the `House` table and in the chain to `Province`. You will get [update anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Objectives).

Avoiding those anomalies is why we normalise schemas.

If many of your queries are going to follow that chain, a better idea is to create a view that joins those tables together. Possibly you might make that a ['materialised view'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view). That's a tricky optimisation balancing act: queries should be quicker, updates to any of the base tables will be slower.

Comment: Exhibiting update anomalies is something that a single table does, so you are misusing the term. You seem to be trying to say something like, without sufficient constraints the DBMS would allow erroneous updates giving inconsistent data.